# Boostrap Fluid, Two Color Background Gradient

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

I am trying to do a vertical two tone background (using css gradient) for my site using twitter bootstrap, such that the gradient ends in the center of the gutter between the spans in a row fluid. I already have the gradient code (shown below) and am trying to figure out what to put for the x's so that the background changes where I want it to. Here is a visual example:

<----------color 1----------><------------------color 2----------------->

<-----span 4--------><-gutter-><------------span 8 ---------------->

What should go in the x's below?

```
  background: #333333; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #333333 0%, #333333 x, #ffffff x, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#333333), color-stop(x,#333333), color-stop(x,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #333333 0%,#333333 x,#ffffff x,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #333333 0%,#333333 x,#ffffff x,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #333333 0%,#333333 x,#ffffff x,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #333333 0%,#333333 x,#ffffff x,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Also relevant: I am not using responsive bootstrap for large monitors and mobile devices, which changes the gutter size.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a simple solution. For my case, with span4 and span8, setting "x" to 33.333% (1/3) did the trick. The beauty of fluid boostrap is that it maintains the ratios of the spans for the entire page.

Drop a comment if you think of any cases where this doesn't work.